# Help with QuickForm Image Upload

Tags: quickform, upload

I have created a form and I am trying to get an image to upload. I have the following set:

```
$this->add(
      'file', // field type
      'image_file', // field name
      'Upload Image', // field label      
      TRUE // is required
    );
```

However, when I submit the file it does not upload anywhere. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed a param to that function. The 4th param is attributes, which you can pass as an empty array, and the 5th param is required, which you can pass TRUE.

Comment: I added the array and it now gives me the following error when submitting: 

"Please correct the following errors in the form fields below:
Upload Image is a required field."

Comment: ALSO, where can I find documentation on the attributes? I would like to specify the filename when uploading...